# Simplest .jpg Display in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I want to display a .jpg (or other picture file) in Python 3. PIL seems to have ended at 2.7. The ways I've looked use python 2. I don't want to change any pixel values, just display the file on the window. What's the simplest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Pillow, it should work on python 2 and 3:

http://python-pillow.github.io

Comment: I ended up installing Anaconda. Ironically, Pillow doesn't come with Anaconda on Windows 7. However, I did just successfully install Pillow.